# Naming a synthetic molecule from QM9 dataset

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, cheminformatics

I was trying to write a name for a synthetic molecule in QM9 dataset. The molecule is:

[image]

is 3-aminooxolane-2-carbonitrile a correct name for this?

Comment: I wonder what dataset do you mean. I've found one with $\ce{C7H10O2}$ isomers. I've also searched through huge GDB-17 (no match).

Comment: .. I mean, no exact match, bu too many substructure matches :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(note: The structure representation is suspicious and confusing. Linear nitrile $\ce{-C#N}$ group is "broken". But I see some software products generate such representation automatically.)

If the structure is really meant saturated, no stereochemistry is indicated.

[image: 3-aminooxolane-2-carbonitrile]
**3-aminooxolane-2-carbonitrile**

(Watch the typo in your proposal *…oxalane.*) But it's not present at PubChem. (SMILES: N#CC1OCCC1N)

Maybe, if unsatured, furan derivative is meant:

[image: 3-aminofuran-2-carbonitrile]
[3-aminofuran-2-carbonitrile](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/12210213)